# Bootstrap mobile menu doesn't show after click in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a wordpress theme with bootstrap feature on [my website](http://dev.galerigadget.com/) but the mobile menu doesn't show up when I resized my browser window to smaller. I've tried everything with another menu code so far still not luck to fix this problem. The mobile menu layout on [my website](http://dev.galerigadget.com/) like screenshot below:
[image: mobile menu layout]

Here my website's mobile menu code:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="container">
    <div id="wrapper">
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php esc_html_e( 'Skip to content', 'gg' ); ?></a>

    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation2" role="navigation">
             <!-- <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="top-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( 'Top Menu', 'gg' ); ?></button> -->

<ul class="mini-cart">

<li> <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url() ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e('View your shopping cart'); ?>" class="cart-parent"> 

<div class="bubblex">
               <div class="inside">
                 <div class="inside-text">
<?php 

echo sprintf(_n('%d', '%d', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);

?></div>
      </div>
    </div>

<i class="cart_control">::before</i></a> 
<?php

echo '<ul class="cart_list">';

echo '<li class="cart-title"><b>Isi Keranjang:</b></li>';

if (sizeof($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents)>0) : foreach ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) :

$_product = $cart_item['data'];

if ($_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity']>0) :

echo '<li class="cart_list_product"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink( intval( $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) ) . '">';

/* echo $_product->get_image(); */

echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_widget_product_title', $_product->get_title(), $_product ) . '</a>';

if($_product instanceof woocommerce_product_variation && is_array($cart_item['variation'])) :

echo woocommerce_get_formatted_variation( $cart_item['variation'] );

endif;

echo '<span class="quantity">' . $cart_item['quantity'] . ' &times; ' . woocommerce_price( $_product->get_price() ) . '</span></li>';

endif;

endforeach;

else: echo '<li class="empty">' . __( 'Keranjang kosong') . '</li>'; endif;

if ( sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents ) > 0 ) :

echo '<li class="total">';

echo  '<span class="amount2">Subtotal</span>' . $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() . '</li>';

echo '<p class="buttons"><a href="' . esc_url( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url() ) . '" class="button wc-forward">Detail</a> <a href="' . esc_url( $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url() ) . '" class="button2 wc-forward">Checkout</a></p>';

endif;

echo '</ul>';

?>

</li> </ul>

            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'top', 'menu_id' => 'top-menu' ) ); ?>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
        <div class="site-branding">
            <?php if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) : ?>
                <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
            <?php else : ?>
                <p class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <p class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></p>
        </div><!-- .site-branding -->

        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <!--   <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"></button> -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">

<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only"><?php _e('Toggle navigation','gg') ?> </span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
<?php wp_nav_menu(
                        array(
                            'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                            'depth'             => 2,
                            'container'         => 'div',
                            'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                            'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                            'menu_id'           => 'main-menu',
                            'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker()
                        )
                    ); ?>
                        </div>

                <!-- <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>  -->
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
        </div><!-- #site-wrapper -->
    </header><!-- #masthead -->

    <div id="content" class="site-content">
```

So how I can fix it? Thanks before

Comment: I would start by fixing the HTML errors you have. See the HTML validator link: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.galerigadget.com%2F

Comment: Start with the things that register as an error and save the warnings for last. You can ignore the warnings about `role`.

Comment: @lucasBonner already fixed some HTML errors. So what's next?

Answer (score 0):

Did you include jQuery & bootstrap.js at the bottom of your page?